# Determining a JS object's prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

What is the best way to determine a JavaScript object's prototype?  I am aware of the following two methods, but I'm not sure which is the "best" way (or if there's a better preferred way) in terms of cross-browser support.

```
if (obj.__proto__ === MY_NAMESPACE.Util.SomeObject.prototype) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if (obj instanceof MY_NAMESPACE.Util.SomeObject) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would say instanceof because the other method seems a bit hackish, and could easily stop working on the next edition of ECMAScript.

Comment: There is a good article that helps you a lot: [http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`instanceof` is prefered. `__proto__` is nonstandard -- specifically, it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` is an ECMAScript 5 function that does the same thing as `__proto__`.

Note that `instanceof` searches the whole prototype chain, whereas `getPrototypeOf` only looks one step up.

Some usage notes:

```
new String() instanceof String  // true

(new String()).__proto__ == String // false!
                                   // the prototype of String is (new String(""))
Object.getPrototypeOf(new String()) == String // FALSE, same as above

(new String()).__proto__ == String.prototype            // true! (if supported)
Object.getPrototypeOf(new String()) == String.prototype // true! (if supported)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is standard, while [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is not (yet - [it will most likely be standard in ECMAScript 6](http://javascript.spec.whatwg.org/#object.prototype.__proto__)).